# ShareActionProvider Rewrite

Tags: java, android, shareactionprovider

I am trying to modify the ShareActionProvider function, so that I can intercept the `onClick` event and prepare the content that I want to share and then call `setShareIntent()`. So far, I've just copied the source code for `ShareActionProvider()` to `MyShareActionProvider()` and trying to compile/execute with my copy of the code.

The `ShareActionProvider()` uses `ActivityChooserModel` and `ActivityChooserView` classes which are defined inside 
`android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel` and

```
android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView
```

Everything seems ok, except for the `activityChooserView.setProvider(this)` call in the `onCreateActionView()` function.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateActionView() {
        // Create the view and set its data model.
        ActivityChooserModel dataModel = ActivityChooserModel.get(mContext, mShareHistoryFileName);
        ActivityChooserView activityChooserView = new ActivityChooserView(mContext);
        activityChooserView.setActivityChooserModel(dataModel);

        // Lookup and set the expand action icon.
        TypedValue outTypedValue = new TypedValue();
        mContext.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionModeShareDrawable, outTypedValue, true);
        Drawable drawable = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(outTypedValue.resourceId);
        activityChooserView.setExpandActivityOverflowButtonDrawable(drawable); 

        activityChooserView.setProvider(this);

        // Set content description
        activityChooserView.setDefaultActionButtonContentDescription(
            R.string.shareactionprovider_share_with_application);
        activityChooserView.setExpandActivityOverflowButtonContentDescription(
            R.string.shareactionprovider_share_with);

        return activityChooserView;
    }
```

It seems that the ActionProvider that is used inside `activityChooser.setProvider()` comes from `android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider` and not `android.view.ActionProvider`.

If I change the import for the `ActionProvider` to `android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider`, then the compile goes through Ok and I can start my app, but when the menu is inflated, I get an error saying `MyShareActionProvider` (which is used in `menu.xml` with the full path and is  an extended class of `android.support.v4.viewActionProvider`) cannot be cast to `android.viewActionProvider`, which is what I guess `inflater.inflate()` returns.

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Thank You,
Gary